# Delphi7Personal EAccessViolation while creating component derived from TImage

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-7

I have an assignment to create a game in Delphi and since the board will be the size 7x7 i wanted to do it by deriving my own component from TImage. Due to the fact that I wanted to have position of all tiles in the board in the array and I wanted to use Create method to do it but whenever I tried I have encountered EAccessViolation, while calling .Create(self)

Here is my component's code:

```
        unit iles1;

       interface

         SysUtils, Classes, Controls, ExtCtrls;

type
  Tiles1 = class(TImage)
  private
      FPlayer:Boolean; //determines whether it is an empty field or a player
      FTeam:Boolean;   //determines the team the tile belogns to
      FBall:Boolean;   //posession of the ball
      {FBackLight : whether it is available to interact  with this component,
      with the method on click after one of the tiles has already been chosen,
      if it is not lit but belongs to the same team, it is flagged as chosen
      but not as lit, this field is used to determine whether i can pass a ball
      to this direction or swap places with other player from the same team}
      FBackLight:Boolean;
      FChosen:Boolean; //whether the player decided to click on it
      {FPostion determines where it is in a table, it ranges from
      36 to 0 where  its position divided by 10 determines the column
      and position mod 10 determines the row}
      FPosition:Byte;
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
     constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent);  override;
    { Public declarations }
  published
     property Team: boolean
        read FTeam
        write FTeam;
     property Ball: boolean
       read FBall
       write FBall;
     property Player:boolean
       read FPlayer
       write FPlayer;
     property BackLight:boolean
       read FBackLight
       write FBackLight;
     property Chosen:boolean
      read FChosen
      write FChosen;
     property Position:byte
      read FPosition
      write FPosition;
     end;

    { property Ball: Boolean;
     //read FHasBall
     //write FSetBall;
     end;}
    { Published declarations }

procedure Register;

implementation
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [Tiles1]);
end;

{Creator procedure calling the Timage creator
and setting parent to self(impossible here, then i will do it in
 main window), visible to true
}
constructor Tiles1.Create(AOwner:TComponent); 
begin
  inherited;
   FPlayer:=false;
   FTeam:=false;
   FBall:=false;
   FBackLight:=false;
   FChosen:=false;
   FPosition:=0;
 end;
end.
```

And here i have my main menu method that uses it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var x,y:Integer;
begin
  for y:=1 to INAROW do begin
    for x:=1 to INAROW do begin
      tiles[x,y].Create(self);
      tiles[x,y].Parent:=self;
      tiles[x,y].Visible:=true;
      tiles[x,y].Top:=(y-1)*(GAPBETWEEN+TILES1HEIGHT)+GAPTOP;
      tiles[x,y].Left:=GAPLEFT+(x-1)*(GAPBETWEEN+TILES1WIDTH);
      tiles[x,y].Width:=TILES1WIDTH;
      tiles[x,y].Height:=TILES1HEIGHT;
      tiles[x,y].Position:=10*x+y;
      tiles[x,y].BackLight:=false;
      tiles[x,y].Ball:=false;
      tiles[x,y].Player:=false;
      tiles[x,y].Chosen:=false;
     end;
  end;
  setAlphaTeam;
  setBetaTeam;
  setTiles;
end;
```

Comment: @mbratch: Bzzt! Wrong answer. :-) `inherited;` works exactly the same, and automatically passes `AOwner` to the ancestor if the constructors are the same signature.

Comment: @KenWhite OK sorry. All of the examples I've seen have been explicit.

Comment: @mbratch: Not a problem. I just wanted to correct your misunderstanding of the problem. (Notice the :-) in my previous comment.)

Comment: This design will likely make your life much harder. Going to be much easier to paint the entire board. A single paintbox or even an empty form with your own paint event or paint method is likely to be best.

Comment: Agree with David in terms of implementing a board instead of a form of tiles. For instance if clicking on a tile selects it, that's 49 handlers to hook up, but if you had a board with one OnClick and then used the coordinates to figure out which tile. You can also get a lot of efficiencies in terms of painting, so you can reduce flicker and such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tiles[X,Y] := Tiles1.Create(self);
```

assuming tiles is an array of Tiles1.

Constructors are effectively class methods, you call them on the class, not the instance.

You are getting an access violation because tiles[X,Y] is nil. If you commented out the create line, you'd get it trying to set the Parent Property.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have totally forgotten about it since I didn't have much experience with Delphi...